# Elasticsearch: sum of each element of array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use an elasticsearch aggregation to 'merge' an array of integers based on a set of filters. I have documents that look like:

```
{
  "arr": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  "name": "test"
}
{
  "arr": [4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  "name": "test"
}
{
  "arr": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "name": "test"
}
```

I want to use an aggregation (or some other es method) to return

```
{
  "arr": [10, 7, 5, 3, 1]
}
```

The aggregation that has come the closest is

```
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "sum_by_index": {
        "filter": {
          "terms": {
            "name": ["test"]
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "arrs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "arr"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this results in a sum per *value* in the array, where I want the sum per *index* of the array. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: you can use a script-field

Comment: @phoet, the script field seemed like the way to do it. The issue is that when I use `doc.arr.values` in the script, it seems to only respond with the *distinct* values in the array. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get the full array inside of the script?

Comment: @cmwright I am also facing the same problem while using `doc`. Though there is an option to achieve this using `_source` which brings the correct results. I have specified that in answer. But I dont want to use `_source`. Have you been able to identify the cause of issue while using `doc`.

Comment: @Richa unfortunately I have solved this, but it is not pretty. I ended up making my documents looks like `"arr": {"1": 10, "2": 5, "3": 4, etc...` and summing those elements. While this works, it uses extra space and is less than ideal. If you solve in a better way, let me know, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @cmwright I did not get you. Now your array is an inner object? Is that so? And what script are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_source` in scripting to achieve the same.By default `groovy`  is supported.

```
 "script" : "_source.arr?.sum(0)"
```